# Type check doesn't remove `Partial` from type

Tags: typescript

Given a `t: Partial<T>` why doesn't Typescript "remove" `Partial` from `T` again when I check that every attribute of `T` is defined in `t`?

Consider this example which doesn't type-check, because in `foo(range)` Typescript still thinks `range` is of type `Partial<Range>`, even though the type checks effectively require that all attributes of `Range` are now defined.

```js
interface Range {
    readonly start: number;
    readonly end: number;
}

const foo = (r: Range) => console.info('Range', r);

const range: Partial<Range> = {start: 10};

if (typeof range.start === "number" && typeof range.end === "number") {
    foo(range)
}
```

Curiously this works:

```js
if (typeof range.start === "number" && typeof range.end === "number") {
    foo({start: range.start, end: range.end})
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, type-checking an object's properties does not result in the type of the object itself being narrowed. For another example which also fails type-checking:

```
type Foo = {
    prop: string | number;
};
const foo: Foo = { prop: 'val' };

const fn = (arg: { prop: string }) => {

};
if (typeof foo.prop === 'string') {
  fn(foo);
}
```

One solution to this general issue would be to use a type guard instead, so as to assert that the *whole object* is of some type if certain conditions are met:

```
const isRange = (arg: Partial<Range>): arg is Range => typeof range.start === "number" && typeof range.end === "number";

const range: Partial<Range> = {start: 10};

if (isRange(range)) {
    foo(range)
}
```

Comment: So discriminiated unions are some kind of special case?  Narrowing only works for literal types?